# What's the shortcut to select the address bar in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, address-bar

What's the shortcut to select Address bar of the current page on Google Chrome?
I always have to create a New tab to write in address bar. So is there any shortcut?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

<kbd>**Control + L**</kbd> on Windows and Linux, or <kbd>**Command + L**</kbd> on Mac.

On Windows, <kbd>**F6**</kbd> or <kbd>**Alt + D**</kbd> also works.

Comment: Ctrl + L and Cmd + L work in Firefox and IE as well. (I would also assume they work in Opera and Safari.)

Comment: wow, it works...  and on linux.  i always used alt+d

Comment: On my Mac I mapped cmd+L to lock screen for consistency with Windows. I've to create a keyboard shortcut specifically for this: macos settings -> `keyboard` -> `shortcuts` -> `app shortcuts` -> select `Google chrome` -> `Open Location...` -> `F6`

Answer (score 10):

I guess you mean to select the address bar. <kbd>ALT+D</kbd> selects the address bar in most of the web browsers around.